# Confusion when comparing numbers with powers

Tags: number-comparison

I am confused about this:

Compare $$7^{26} - 7^{25} = 7^{25}(6)$$

This is what I have calculated:

\begin{align}&(1.0 \times 7^{26}) -  (1.0 \times 7^{25})  
\\&=(10\times 7^{25}) - (1.0 \times 7^{25})  
\\&=7^{25}(10-1)  
\\&=7^{25}(9)   
\end{align}

and this does not equal $7^{25}(6)$

Am I correct, or have I missed something?

Comment: You just to have to use the fact that $7^{26} = (6+1)\times7^{25}$

Comment: It looks to me like you changed a 7 into a 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

notice that $$7^{26} = 7 \times 7^{25}$$

$$7^{26} \neq 10 \times 7^{25}$$

Hence $$7^{26} - 7^{25} = 7 \times 7^{25} - 7^{25} = (7-1) \times 7^{25}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer has made it clear to me, and I now understand.